# How the number of connections of a usenet provider change something?

Tags: bandwidth, usenet, newsgroup

At work, we are speaking about the interest to have 10 or 30 connections simultanly to a usenet provider.

Some guys said it change nothing because the 10 or 30 threads will take all the bandwidth available, so the download time will be the same.

Another guys said it change something because you can download more file at the same time.

Someone have a GOOD explanation to this problematic ? :)

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NNTP protocol has a lot of latency, so running multiple simultaneous connections can improve the speed of actions, particularly if there's a lot of back and forth with the server.  (More recent versions of the protocol have support for streaming, but not many clients or servers know about this yet.)  10-30 sounds like overkill to me, though; usually you get the benefits of avoiding latency with 4-8 connections.

The best thing to do would be to test a variety of different numbers of connections for the exact thing you're trying to do and see which one is faster, though.  It's going to depend on what types of actions you're taking.